# two scale positive and negative in the same axis - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.c]

How can I do this in Excel ?

Create in the same **y axis** positive and negative numbers in different scale, using the same **x axis** scale.

Just found a solution with secondary axis, but that does not quite solve my problem.

Comment: please see the picture I attached

Comment: I don't think you can do this. A workaround can be to prepare two graphs, and move them on top of each other.